# pfSense L2 firewall not blocking half of DHCP traffic

Tags: firewall, dhcp, bridge, pfsense

I have a pfSense instance (NetGate SG-series), with setup:

- 802.11q enabled
- LAN ports 1 (`LANP`) and 2 (`LANB`) with VLAN assignments
- Interfaces assigned and enabled

`LANP`:

- (1, 5t) tag configuration
- Static IP configuration
- DHCP server bound to this interface
- Block BOOTP 67-68 from any source to the secondary `LANB` server's static IP
- Allow BOOTP 67-68 and tag `bootp_lanp`
- Allow all traffic from LANP subnet to any destination
- Connected to a single-host network with a node running a DHCP client

`LANB`:

- (2, 5t) tag configuration
- DHCP client IP configuration
- Connected to a single-host network with a static-IP node running a DHCP server
- Block any traffic tagged `bootp_lanp`

`LANP` and `LANB` are bridged. The bridge interface is assigned but has no firewall rules, and the tunables are their default (as in, `pfil` is on for the member and off for the bridge).

This is *supposed* to act as an L2 firewall so that the node on `LANP` receives DHCP service from the pfSense instance and not the secondary server connected to `LANB`, but that doesn't happen.

If `LANB` is disconnected, the `LANP` DHCP service functions successfully, but if `LANB` is connected, the secondary DHCP server always wins. The BOOTP block rule even registers state activity on `LANP` but nothing is actually blocked, because the node on `LANP` still receives DHCP service from the secondary `LANB` server.

Nothing I have tried is able to block this traffic. How do I block this traffic and force precedence of the pfSense DHCP server instance?